# Not able to add path in zsh profile, valid directory showing not found have tried in both bash and zsh

Tags: bash, macos, zsh

```
nikitapant@IND-FVFXL93UHV29 ~ % ls
Applications        Library         Postman Agent
DataGripProjects    Movies          Public
Desktop         Music           Result_33.csv
Documents       Pictures        spark
Downloads       Postman
nikitapant@IND-FVFXL93UHV29 ~ % pwd
/Users/vaibhavkumar
nikitapant@IND-FVFXL93UHV29 ~ % echo $PATH
/Users/vaibhavkumar:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
nikitapant@IND-FVFXL93UHV29 ~ % source ~/.zshrc
/Users/vaibhavkumar/.zshrc:5: /Users/vaibhavkumar/spark not found
nikitapant@IND-FVFXL93UHV29 ~ % vi ~/.zshrc
nikitapant@IND-FVFXL93UHV29 ~ %
```

As this folder is available at the specified location but showing not found, not able to find any clue.

[image: png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `$`.

```
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/vaibhavkumar/spark
```

---

With the dollar sign, the undefined parameter first expands to the empty string, leaving you with

```
export =/Users/vaibhavkumar/spark
```

A word prefixed with `=` in `zsh` tries to do path lookup on that word. Since there is no file named `/Users/vaibhavkumar/spark` in any directory in your `PATH` variable, you get the observed error.